# Save a table efficiently in Python

Tags: python, pandas

My original data is in a plain text file. It is made up of 1255 rows and 43 columns. Instead of working with all the data, I want to create a text file that has only the data I am interested in.

For example, let's say I want to select all the data that verify the condition: `1 < column 26 < 7`. Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import csv
import os

data = np.genfromtxt('data.txt', dtype = None)

path = os.getcwd()

csvfile = path + '/subgp1.txt'

counter = 0
with open(csvfile, 'w') as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, delimiter = '\t')

    for row in range(len(data)):
        if (data[row][26] > 1 and data[row][26] < 7):
            counter += 1
            writer.writerow([counter, data[row][1], data[row][2], data[row][3], ... data[row][42]])
```

The last line in the code is I simply write the data all over again to the `subgp1.txt` I created. Is there a more efficient way to do the same thing?

My reasoning is:

**1.** The last line should be simplified. In my case, the last line looks something like this:

```
writer.writerow([counter, '%-8d' % data[row][1], data[row][2], 
                     data[row][3], '%-2.6f' % data[row][4], '%-2.6f' % data[row][5], 
                     '%-2.6f' % data[row][6], '%-2.2f' % data[row][7], 
                     '%-2.2f' % data[row][8], '%-2.2f' % data[row][9], ..., '%-2.4f' % data[row][42]])
```

**2.** I have 42 columns so that's a waste of time. I am sure there is a neater and faster way to do this.

Is the package `pandas` more efficient in tasks similar to the one I seek?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing:

```
writer.writerow([counter, data[row][1], data[row][2], data[row][3], ... data[row][42]])
```

You can concatenate `[counter]` with a slice of `data[row]`:

```
writer.writerow([counter] + data[row][1:])
```

Better yet, you can iterate over the data rows directly:

```
for row in data:
    if (row[26] > 1 and row[26] < 7):
        counter += 1
        writer.writerow([counter] + row[1:])
```

Comment: I get an error: `IndexError: invalid index`. Even when I write `print data[0][4:15]` I get the same error `IndexError: invalid index`. I guess this has to do with the format I am reading the data: `np.genfromtxt`.

Comment: Note: when I write `print data[0][4]` the code executes without errors.

Comment: Then you must have rows of varying length. You should use `[1:]` instead. Please see my revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to import **collections** for this, but then you can do this:

```
for ctr,row in enumerate(collections.ifilter(lambda r:r[26]>1 and r[26]<7, data)):
    writer.writerow([ctr, "%-8d' % row[1], row[2], row[3], 
                     '%-2.6f' %row[4],...])
```

The question is what do you consider inefficient?  Specifying the format for each field at a time?

If you know what the formats are ahead of time, you can use that.

```
format_strings = ('%d', '%-8d', '%s', '%s', '%-2.6f', ...)
for ctr,row in enumerate(collections.ifilter(lambda r:r[26]>1 and r[26]<7, data)):
    writer.writerow([f%v for f,v in zip(format_strings, [ctr]+row)])
```

Comment: you're right, it's inefficient because: 1- I'm specifying the format for each field at a time 2- writing explicitly that I want to add all the columns of my table to another 'subtable' (knowing that I have 42 columns! What if I had 100 columns? 200 columns?). I thought there's an efficient and better way to code exactly what I am looking for.